# Get Observable<T> from HttpClient.get with options

Tags: angular, http, generics

Usually, I perform a get request using Angular HttpClient like in this example:

```
this.http
   .get<Project>('/api/projects/' + id)
   .subscribe(p => {
    // p is typed as Project
    this.project = p;
  });
```

The type parameter `Project` defines the expected response. `HttpCLient.get<T>()` returns an `Observable<T>`.

I now need to add some options to the request, like i.e. so:

```
getRequestOptions() {
   var headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + this.auth.EMail + ':' + this.auth.Token);
   return { headers: this.getRequestOptions() };
}

// Somewhere else   
this.http.get<Project>(url, this.getRequestOptions())
         .subscribe(p => { 
             // p is HttpEvent<Project> with no (direct?) access to the
             // returned object, just a property called type
         });
```

This calls a different overload of the `get()` method, which for some reasons return not an `Observable<T>` but an `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`. Apart from that being bad design in my opinion:

How do I use HttpEvent? It only contains one property called `type`. I am aware that there are derived types, in case of a get request probably `HttpResponse<T>`. Do I really need to deal with all that type switching and casting stuff, just because I am using RequestOptions?

What is the background of this design decision? Why don' all overloads return the same type and share a common usage pattern?

Comment: Just tried it on my machine and with angular 5 I don't see your problem. I'll only get a `HttpResponse<T>` from the client if the options object has a property `observe` with the value `response`. Otherwise you'll get the `T` directly as stated in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response).

Comment: I don't see this issue with angular 6 either, the only time I get `HttpEvent<T>` as a response is when using the `observe` prop with the `event` value. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nurcql?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstar-wars.service.ts). I'm not 100% sure here, but I have a feeling your issue may be caused by the way you are constructing your headers. Looking at the code, it should be throwing a call stack size exceeded error due to the recursion, or at the very least causing some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong about the code in my question: There is a stack overflow error due to the recursive function call, as Und3rTow pointed out in his comment. Secondly, `HttpHeaders` is immutable obviously. The `append()` method returns a new `HttpHeaders` object but doesn't alter the original one. As an alternative to using the modified object it is possible to pass key value pairs in the constructor. The working code is:

```
getRequestOptions() {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + this.auth.EMail + ':' + this.auth.Token});
    var options = {      
      headers: headers 
    };
    return options;
}
```